# Pinging Google DNS server into background sometimes results into failure

Tags: android, service, timer, background

I am building a simple Android app to check if active internet connection is available on my phone. For checking this I am using a service which is running into background every 30 seconds and "pings" the Google's DNS server to check if there is a response.

This is my class used for checking internet status:

```
public class NetworkStatus {

private static final String GOOGLE_DNS_SERVER = "8.8.8.8";
private static final String CLOUDFLARE_DNS_SERVER = "1.1.1.1";
private static final String TAG = "OUTGOING-NET-STATUS";
private static final String RETRY_TAG = "DNS-CHECK";

boolean pingDnsServerSuccessful() {
    boolean success = false;
    int count = 0;
    final int MAX_TRIES = 15;

    while (!success && count++ < MAX_TRIES) {
        Log.d(RETRY_TAG, "Retry value: " + count + " out of " + MAX_TRIES);
        success = isDnsServerReachable(CLOUDFLARE_DNS_SERVER) || isDnsServerReachable(GOOGLE_DNS_SERVER);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (success) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Outgoing Internet Traffic is Enabled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error reaching Outgoing Traffic");
    }

    return success;

}

private boolean isDnsServerReachable(String dnsServer) {
    int connectionTimeout = 250;

    try {
        return InetAddress.getByName(dnsServer).isReachable(connectionTimeout);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: Error while pinging " + dnsServer + " DNS server: " + e);
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

and this is the code which triggers the background timer within the service:

```
public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();

    networkStatus = new NetworkStatus();
    notificationManager = new NotificationManager();

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();

    //schedule the timer, to wake up every 30 seconds
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 30000); //
}

/**
 * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
 */
public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            Log.i("in timer", "in timer ++++  " + (counter++));

                if (networkStatus.pingDnsServerSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i(PING_TAG, "Active Internet Connection");

                    if (!notificationManager.getLastSentNotificationType().equals(NotificationType.INTERNET_UP)) {
                        Log.i(NOTIFICATION_TAG, "Internet ON");
                        notificationManager.sendNotification(getApplicationContext(), NotificationType.INTERNET_UP);
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.i(PING_TAG, "No Internet Connection");

                    if (!notificationManager.getLastSentNotificationType().equals(NotificationType.INTERNET_DOWN)) {
                        Log.i(NOTIFICATION_TAG, "Internet OFF");
                        notificationManager.sendNotification(getApplicationContext(), NotificationType.INTERNET_DOWN);
                    }
                }

        }
    };
}
```

Everything works fine for a random amount of time (minutes/hours) when suddenly the DNS server can't be reached anymore when app is running in background and phone is locked. Activating the phone's screen is immediately resulting into a success while pinging the server.

Here are some logs reflecting the behaviour:
[Logs](https://pastebin.com/HCnu2Prk)

Does anybody have a clue why is this happening? I highly doubt that Google or Cloudflare DNS server becomes unresponsive...

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Doze mode.  To save power, background requests are limited to a small window every 15 minutes or so for requests.  In addition, background processes can be killed at any time.

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do, but there are 100% better ways to do it.  For example, JobScheduler allows you to schedule a job to go off only if the internet is connected.  No need to ping a server manually, and no need to do all the work to avoid Doze.

Comment: Thanks Gabe! The purpose of the app would be to notify me if I have active internet connection or not even if I am connected to wifi/mobile data (often I get connected to wifi networks which are not linked to an internet WAN). I will read about the JobScheduler and give it a try. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Had done some research, indeed the problem was caused by the Doze mode. I've managed to reproduce the problem by simulating doze mode using adb commands `adb shell dumpsys battery unplug` and `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle` which forced the simulator to enter into idle state. I read about the Job Scheduler as well but from what I've seen into Android docs, "The system does not allow JobScheduler to run" while into Doze mode so I will investigate how to overcome this.

Comment: Just in case anyone needs, I found a great article regarding how to work with alarms/job schedules into Doze mode: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/diving-into-doze-mode-for-developers/

Comment: And a sample app from the above article: https://github.com/bignerdranch/doze-logger